# Finding closest point perpendicular to B

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

[image]

Given:

```
A = 8,4
B = 4,8
C = 4,4
D = ?,?
```

From point C (4,4) (red dot) how would I find the coordinate that would be perpendicular to AB and CD being parallel to AB? (green dot)

In the end I just need to find the coordinates of point D.

Comment: Point D satisfies two conditions: (1) $CD$ is parallel to $AB$; (2) $CD$ is perpendicular to $BD$. Expressing those in terms of cross-products derives the system of two equations with two variables $x,y$ for $D(x,y)$.

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I mean plus that BD needs to be perpendicular to AB. I really can't figure out the formula for that.

Comment: Take the slopes of lines DB and AB and multiply them to get -1. Solve the two equations you get. to get equation of the line DB. Repeat process for CD and DB.

Comment: But to calculate the slope of DB I need to know the coordinate of D right? Which I don't know

Comment: Doh. Let $x$ and $y$ be the coordinates of $D$ - now you know them. Then $CD=(x-4,y-4)$, $BD=(x-8,y-4)$. Then (1) $CD \cdot AB = |AB| \cdot |CD|$, (2) $CD \cdot BD = 0 $. Rewrite them using $x$ and $y$ and solve for $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=(ax,ay), B=(bx,by), C=(cx,cy), D=(dx,dy)$. Then vectors are $BD=(dx-bx,dy-by), CD=(dx-cx,dy-cy), AB=(bx-ax, by-ay)$.

Let $|BD|, |CD|, |AB|$ be lengths of corresponding vectors.

Point D satisfies two conditions: (1) $CD$ is parallel to $AB$; (2) $CD$ is perpendicular to $BD$.

Rewriting those using dot products gives:

(1) $(dx-cx)(bx-ax)+(dy-cy)(by-ay)= \\ \sqrt{(dx-cx)^2+(dy-cy)^2} \cdot  \sqrt{(bx-ax)^2+(by-ay)^2} $

and

(2) $(dx-cx)(dx-bx)+(dy-cy)(dy-by)=0$.

Solve the system of (1) and (2) for $dx$ and $dy$ for given $ax,ay,bx,by,cx,cy$.

Comment: With the first dot product I couldn't get further than this: `(dx-3)(4)+0= |CD|⋅ 4`. And with the second one I get 2 possible answers from which one of them is the right one and the other one is the same y as B. (I'm really not good at math but I am trying my best I wrote it all out)

Comment: Rewrite $|CD|$ via it's coordinates using $|Z|=\sqrt {Zx^2+Zy^2}$. The second one is fine - there are actually two points $D$ that satisfy the conditions, one of them `to the left` of $AB$, another - `to the right`.

Comment: Thank you, I understand the second one now but could you perhaps explain rewriting CD a little more? I really don't get it..

Comment: |Z| would be sqrt of (dx - 3)² + (dy -2)² right? But I really don't understand what to do from there on

Comment: From there on you've got two equiations for two variables, $dx$ and $dy$. Solve them to get the desired $D=(dx,dy)$.

Comment: @SinanSamet I've updated the answer to reflect the idea more basically

Comment: Thank you I will try my best to solve it

Comment: This really doesn't work for me. I have to converse it later on into a formula so I can use it with javascript to make a program out of it so it shouldn't be based on trying things out but getting the answer with the formula straight on. It doesn't allow me to have multiple options. If I am right (might be wrong and stupid) this is just to see if the coordinates you have is right. But what I need is to get the coordinates of it instead of knowing if it's right.

Comment: Solution of the system of two equations above is the formula which expresses $dx$ and $dy$ directly from known coordinates of points $A, B, C$. Solving two-variable systems of simple equations is quite a typical homework for teens. This Q&A site discourages direct answers for homework questions but encourages answers that lead to questioner's own efforts. As you may have already noticed, there are way too few people who would bother stuffing your numbers into the system and yielding you an exact formula on a silver plate. Try doing something and ask further questions if any.

Comment: That makes perfect sense thank you.

Comment: I am trying out multiple coordinates and sometimes in statement 1 I get for example as answer 8,49 while the calculation is 8 and it's only the answer that gets to be a decimal sometimes. Is that normal?

Comment: You mean that your calculated value $(8,49)$ differs from pre-defined known answer? Would you provide the example script that leads you to that?

Comment: Apologies in the Netherlands we use , for decimals instead of . but having A = 1,5 B = 4,9 C = 5,3 and D = 7,5 I got (7-5)(4-1)+(5-3)(8-5) = 12.72 while the calculation would be 12

Comment: I was trying to find the answer by filling in the correct D. (I don't know if this is the correct way to go with it.)

Comment: I did notice though that in the statement  (dx−cx)(bx−ax)+(dy−cy)(by−ay) either both sides are equal or the left side is 0

Comment: Your specified $D=(7,5)$ doesn't satisfy your original problem, because $CD$ isn't parallel to $AB$. Your $D$ is not the correct $D$.

Comment: However, changing $B$ to $B=(4,8)$ looks right. Try to substitute all the points for this new $B$.

Comment: Oh my apologies I meant B = (4,8) I just typed it wrong in the comment. But still the left side of the equation is 12 while the right side is 12.72

Comment: (7-5)(4-1)+(5-3)(8-5) = 4.24 * 3 would be 12 = 12.72 which would be not correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19518/discussion-between-mbaitoff-and-sinan-samet).

Answer (score 0):

Shortest distance would be zero . Since the point C does not lie on AB, there definitely exists a line CD perpendicular to AB.

Comment: Maybe I am explaining it wrong (my math skills are just basic) but in my example the line x would be perpendicular to AB. So I need the closest coordinate to the x line from C. CD being parallel to AB. I editted my question a little instead of the closest to the perpendicular of AB I want the CD being parallel to AB. In the end I just need the coordinates of point D